# Scrapy not crawling all links

Tags: regex, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using Scrapy to crawl and scrap site of a fixed domain . I want to crawl into the site that matches a fixed regular expression and ignore the rest. The code works perfectly well but only returns around 10-15 pages out of atleast 1000 pages. The code is:

```
name = "xyz"
allowed_domains = ["xyz.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.xyz.com"] 
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\/V-\d{7}\/[\w\S]+']),callback='parse_item'),)



def parse_item(self, response):
 sel = Selector(response)

 title = sel.xpath("//h1[@class='no-bd']/text()").extract()
 print title
```

Can anyone please tell me what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your code is the problem, but that the site you are crawling has a limit as too how many requests it will handle from a specific IP in a given period. You could try implementing some `sleep(2)` calls in between and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

if you provide a callback, Scrapy assumes you will return a list of `Request` objects from the parse function. If you'd rather it will follow the links by itself, add a `follow=True` to the rule.

Also note, that this will only follow links that match the regex you specified. If you'd like to crawl the whole site, and parse only the links that match to the regex, add another rule to follow everything:

```
rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=[r'\/V-\d{7}\/[\w\S]+']),
              callback='parse_item'), 
              follow=True),
         Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor()),
        )
```

I've been only using Scrapy for a week, so I might be wrong...